# C# Naudio WaveOutEvent stop outputting audio when reached silent even when audio is playing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, naudio, equalizer

I am currently working on a project which is using Naudio on Unity. I have done my equalizer part of code. But I realize that when the WaveOutEvent hits the silent part of the playing audio, it will stop outputting the audio even when the audio is still playing and not stopped.

When I commented on the part which transform the buffer, the problem stated above will not occur. I have restarted my Unity project and my computer but the problem is not yet solved.

```
public EqualizedAudio(ISampleProvider sampleProvider = null) {
    equalizer = new();

    if (sampleProvider != null) {
        this.sampleProvider = sampleProvider;
    }

    filter = new BiQuadFilter[equalizer.Length];
    CreateFilter();
}

private void CreateFilter() {
    for (int i = 0; i < equalizer.Length; i++) {
        if (filter[i] == null) {
            filter[i] = BiQuadFilter.PeakingEQ(sampleProvider.WaveFormat.SampleRate,
                equalizer.equalizerBands[i].CenterFrequency, equalizer.equalizerBands[i].QFactor,
                equalizer.equalizerBands[i].Gain);
        }
        else {
            filter[i].SetPeakingEq(sampleProvider.WaveFormat.SampleRate,
                equalizer.equalizerBands[i].CenterFrequency, equalizer.equalizerBands[i].QFactor,
                equalizer.equalizerBands[i].Gain);
        }

    }
}

public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
    int sampleRead = sampleProvider.Read(buffer, offset, count);

    if (updated) {
        CreateFilter();
        updated = false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sampleRead; i++) {
        for (int band = 0; band < equalizer.Length; band++) {
            buffer[offset + i] = filter[band].Transform(buffer[offset + i]);
        }
    }
    return sampleRead;
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if your `Read` method returns 0, playback will stop. If you want playback to continue, always return `count` and fill the buffer with silence